# Creating a shared folder between unprivileged users

Tags: server, permissions, directory, shared-folders

This may be a repeat question, but I wasn't able to answer this specific question anywhere else.  My school uses Ubuntu to run their server. My friends and I have accounts on the server, but aren't granted `sudo` access.  All we want to do is have a shared folder.

I thought of adding my friends' accounts to a group and changing the group of the folder to that group, but I couldn't do that without `sudo` access.  I tried `chmod a+rwx`, but my friend still couldn't `cd` into it.  Is there any way to do this easily?  Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Your home directory probably lacks execute permissions for other users, so they can't enter it (or any subdirectory within). Use `/tmp` if you want a common area.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Is it a terrible idea for me to make my folder readable instead?

Comment: I doubt you can. Changing your home directory's permissions would need write access to its parent directory, which I doubt you have.

Comment: I think a symlink would be better, no? Create a directory in `/tmp`, create links to that directory in each user's home folder.

Comment: Doesn't everything in /tmp get deleted periodically though?